# Get value from input text HTML and immediately using it

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have input text and some text in HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" maxlength='13' size='13'  onChange="no_user_id_change();">

<p> Your ID is: {{id from input type goes here when I type Enter in input type...}} </p>
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function no_user_id_change() {
        var userId = $("#user_id").val();      
    }
</script>
```

My question:

How can I get the `user id` from the `input` text when user type Enter?

Comment: Please check the answers on the linked question. Here is the [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rq5x7coh/) of the same answer. Note that `onchange` will not work in your case, use `key***` events. Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: @Tushar I know the answer if I display it on `alert`, but what I need is how to get the variable `userId` from the `<script>` and display it in HTML tag `<p>`??

Comment: `$('p').text(userId)`

Comment: You can add a `span` element with ID inside `p` and change it's value. [**Another Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rq5x7coh/1/)